# Best Digital recorder for use as a ‘body pack’ + good field recorder?

Tags: digital-recording, video

I'm looking at getting something to use as a 'body pack' as opposed to using a wireless setup when using a lavalier microphone.

I've looked into Tascam DR-08 vs. Zoom H1 or other.

I found a comparison of these two here (great blog for video):

http://cheesycam.com/tascam-dr-08-vs-zoom-h1-continued/

I've seen various information recommending both of these recorders along with the negatives including build quality and battery problems of the H1.

I thought that that the Zoom H1 with it's protective cover over the mics and the offset angles are great pluses for this device for this use.

What are people's thoughts on ultra compact digital recorders? Any suggestions or recommendations?

Comment: Found another contender: The Tascam DR-05 http://cheesycam.com/tascam-dr-05-review-video/

Comment: Does anyone have a Zoom H1 or used one. Or have any experience with anything else? What do people use?

Comment: Recorded with a Zoom H2: [Robin M'aime](http://www.box.net/shared/iuoyur65bx). (The [H2](http://www.samsontech.com/products/productpage.cfm?prodid=1916) is similar o the H1, but has four mics in a quadrophonic pattern.)

Comment: I use a Zoom H4n for other purposes, but have been very happy with the quality.

Answer (score 9):

The specific feature set will determine if it is appropriate for you application, though from my experience most of the high end field recorders are very good quality.

The Zoom series have a great (well deserved) reputation for being relatively easy to use, and being kind to your wallet.

If you wish to supply your own mic, you may wish to find one without inbuilt microphones as it may be cheaper.

If you do not want to supply your own mic, my experience has been that the inbuilt mics are adequate for recording dialogue, in say an interview.

If you're planning to record with the device on the talent (and want the recorder to be as discreet as possible), I would suggest investing in lapel mic (just the mic not the transmitter), and plug that into the field recorder to get the mic as close as possible.

Answer (score 2):

I have a [Zoom H2](http://www.zoom.co.jp/english/products/h2/) and I'm very impressed with the sound quality. It has 4 built-in mics giving it a 360° recording capability. Battery life is poor though so a couple of sets of high-capacity rechargeables is in order.

Comment: I use an H2 as well and love it. I used it in-between computers, to produce serviceable tracks.

Answer (score 1):

I have a [Marantz PMD620](http://www.d-mpro.com/users/folder.asp?FolderID=4313) & it works very nicely -- the builtin microphone sounds very clear, battery life is good, it has timestamping, and it takes SD cards. I'm not a professional or audio expert, but I'm very happy with it.